# Python loop and if statment weird issues

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, sap-ase

Ok, I dont understand what is happening.  I am looping over output from my query.  A pretty normal loop and if.  The issue is when I try to do results[o] < 30.  It does not print out the variable.  There are column data less than 30 for some reason they don't print.  Even if I print a string.  Nothing happens. The else statement will print but not the if.  On my flask template I have similar code and it works. What am I doing incorrectly. The results[0] is of type int.  So I don't know what the issue is.  I am not getting any errors.

```
    for recordset in return_stored_procedure:
        results.append(dict(zip(sp_column_names, recordset)))
        if results[0]['days_column'] <= 30:
           print variable
        else:
           print variable
```

***update*****
Figured out the issues thanks everyone.  Made the corrections now I will remove what I don't want from the list.

```
    for l in sp_results:
        if l['column'] < 30:
            newlist.append(l)
```

Now on to making a list comprehension. Instead of this loop.

Comment: well, you are always checking the first item in `results`, which is not changing in the loop you are showing, so there's no reason to expect that check to ever change....

Comment: Also, if as you say `results[0]` is of type `int`, then `results[0]['days_column']` would throw a `TypeError`, because `int` objects are not sub-scriptable. So your question doesn't make a whole-lot of sense. I suggest you provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You can see from the line before, the OP is appending a `dictionary` to the `results` `list` (I think): `results.append(dict(...))`.

Comment: @JoeIddon right, I see that, but that will not change what is in index 0 (except for maybe the first iteration). It almost certainly isn't what the OP wants, and again, it is not consistent with the OPs claim that `results[0]` is an `int`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, yes I hadn't considered the first `index`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I had a typo when I posted.  Should have been result[c].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what you want, but I assume you want to check the `data_column` `key` of the `dict` that you have just `appended` to `results`. Again, I'm not sure if this is what is desired, but you can get the last element from `results` by taking an `index` of `-1`:

```
for recordset in return_stored_procedure:
    results.append(dict(zip(sp_column_names, recordset)))
    if results[-1]['days_column'] <= 30:
       print variable
    else:
       print variable
```

Comment: I've achieved my goal.